# two Arraylist Compare same after update java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Compare Two Arraylist and after same element value in  both arraylist after it one Arraylist Value Update in second element. same element find  that times give error:[image]

```
for (Thumbnail thumbnail : videoList1){

    for (Giphy giphy : giphyList) {


        if (thumbnail.getVideoID().equals(giphy.getVideoID())) {

            thumbnail.setThumbUp(giphy.getThumbUp());
            thumbnail.setThumbDown(giphy.getThumbDown());
            videoList1.add(thumbnail);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify a list, while iterating trough it. Try this.

```
ArrayList<Thumbnail> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
for (Thumbnail thumbnail : videoList1){
    for (Giphy giphy : giphyList) {


        if (thumbnail.getVideoID().equals(giphy.getVideoID())) {

            thumbnail.setThumbUp(giphy.getThumbUp());
            thumbnail.setThumbDown(giphy.getThumbDown());
            tmp.add(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
videoList1.addAll(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add (or remove) anything to `videoList1` while iterating through it.
Instead create a new list before iterating, add items to that temporary list, and after iterating - add whole temporary list to your `videoList1`:

```
List<Thumbnail> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
for (Thumbnail thumbnail : videoList1){

    for (Giphy giphy : giphyList) {


        if (thumbnail.getVideoID().equals(giphy.getVideoID())) {

            thumbnail.setThumbUp(giphy.getThumbUp());
            thumbnail.setThumbDown(giphy.getThumbDown());
            toAdd.add(thumbnail);
        }
    }

}
videoList1.addAll(toAdd);
```